# Invalid roslaunch XML syntax

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I am unable to use the following launch file without getting "Invalid roslaunch XML syntax".
Any suggestions? (I'm a novice)
Thanks in advance.

```
<launch>
  <!-- Visualization and SLAM nodes use same data, so just subscribe once and relay messages -->
  <node name="odom_relay" type="relay" pkg="topic_tools" args="/base_controller/odom /base_controller/odom_relay" />
  <node name="scan_relay" type="relay" pkg="topic_tools" args="/base_scan /base_scan_relay" />
  <node name="camera_info_relay" type="relay" pkg="topic_tools" args="/camera/data_throttled_camera_info /camera/data_throttled_camera_info_relay" />
  <node name="republish_rgb" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" args="theora in:=/camera/data_throttled_image raw out:=/camera/data_throttled_image_relay" />
  <node name="republish_depth" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" args="compressedDepth in:=/camera/data_throttled_image_depth raw out:=/camera/data_throttled_image_depth_relay" />

  <!-- SLAM client side -->
  <!-- args: "delete_db_on_start" and "udebug" -->
  <group ns="rtabmap">
    <node name="rtabmap" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" output="screen" args="--delete_db_on_start">
          <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="base_link"/>

          <param name="subscribe_depth" type="bool" value="true"/>
          <param name="subscribe_laserScan" type="bool" value="true"/>

          <remap from="odom" to="/base_controller/odom_relay"/>
          <remap from="scan" to="/base_scan_relay"/>

          <remap from="rgb/image" to="/camera/data_throttled_image_relay"/>
          <remap from="depth/image" to="/camera/data_throttled_image_depth_relay"/>
          <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/camera/data_throttled_camera_info_relay"/>

          <param name="queue_size" type="int" value="10"/>

          <!-- RTAB-Map's parameters -->
          <param name="RGBD/PoseScanMatching" type="string" value=“true”/>
          <param name="RGBD/LocalLoopDetectionSpace" type="string" value="true"/>
          <param name="LccIcp/Type" type="string" value="2"/>
          <param name="LccBow/MinInliers" type="string" value="5"/>
          <param name="LccBow/InlierDistance" type="string" value="0.1"/>
          <param name="RGBD/AngularUpdate" type="string" value="0.01"/>
          <param name="RGBD/LinearUpdate" type="string" value="0.01"/>
          <param name="Rtabmap/TimeThr" type="string" value="700"/>
          <param name="Mem/RehearsalSimilarity" type="string" value="0.45"/>
    </node>

  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz"/>

  <!-- Construct point cloud of the latest throttled data -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="points_xyzrgb" args="load rtabmap/point_cloud_xyzrgb standalone_nodelet">
    <remap from="rgb/image"       to="/camera/data_throttled_image_relay"/>
    <remap from="depth/image"     to="/camera/data_throttled_image_depth_relay"/>
    <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/camera/data_throttled_camera_info_relay"/>
    <remap from="cloud"           to="voxel_cloud" />

    <param name="queue_size" type="int" value="10"/>
    <param name="voxel_size" type="double" value="0.01"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot#Remote_mapping

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224476/invalid-roslaunch-xml-syntax/) by [blane](https://answers.ros.org/users/25521/blane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-01-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-19**:
Please add your version of ROS, what OS you're running, what version, how you installed ROS, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many tools out there to validate XML. I've used the [**xmllint**](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) commandline tool to some success. Assuming your launchfile is `foobar.launch`, it produces this output:

```
$ xmllint foobar.launch
foobar.launch:28: parser error : AttValue: " or ' expected
      <param name="RGBD/PoseScanMatching" type="string" value=“true”/>
                                                              ^
foobar.launch:28: parser error : attributes construct error
      <param name="RGBD/PoseScanMatching" type="string" value=“true”/>
                                                              ^
foobar.launch:28: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag param line 28
      <param name="RGBD/PoseScanMatching" type="string" value=“true”/>
                                                              ^
foobar.launch:51: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: group line 11 and launch
     </launch>
     ^
foobar.launch:52: parser error : Premature end of data in tag launch line 1
^
```

Based on that, it looks like you have some weird characters instead of double quotes (") around your value attributes, and you appear to be missing the end tag of your group (`<group ns="rtabmap">`) which would be
`</group>`.

---

Originally posted by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) with karma: 790 on 2016-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blane](https://answers.ros.org/users/25521/blane/) on 2016-01-22**:
Thank you!
Solved the issue.